# Recover GItLab Account with 2FA

Tags: gitlab

I have set up two factor authentication on my account some time ago, but I lost my phone and can't find the backup codes.

How can I restore the access to my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 ways to remove 2FA (see here: [Gitlab support](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/support/#removal-of-2fa-a-name2faremovala))

Then, you have to send an email to support[at]gitlab.com with the information.